# Creating a 3D face mesh for Kinects depth field

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

The Kinect SDK comes with an example of creating a face mesh on the colour stream. That looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPtJt.jpg

I want to create a 3D mesh for the depth stream

My code currently looks as follows:

```
private EnumIndexableCollection<FeaturePoint, PointF> facePoints;
private EnumIndexableCollection<FeaturePoint, Vector3DF> depthPoints;

public void DrawFaceModel(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    if (!this.lastFaceTrackSucceeded || this.skeletonTrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
        return;

    var faceModelPts = new List<Point>();
    var faceModelPts3D = new List<Point3D>();
    var faceModel = new List<FaceModelTriangle>();
    var faceModel3D = new List<FaceModelTriangle3D>();

    for (int i = 0; i < this.facePoints.Count; i++)
    {
        faceModelPts3D.Add(new Point3D(this.depthPoints[i].X + 0.5f, this.depthPoints[i].Y + 0.5f, this.depthPoints[i].Z + 0.5f));
    }

    FaceDataPoints.Number_of_Points = this.facePoints.Count;

    foreach (var t in ImageData.faceTriangles)
    {
        var triangle = new FaceModelTriangle3D();
        triangle.Point1_3D = faceModelPts3D[t.First];
        triangle.Point2_3D = faceModelPts3D[t.Second];
        triangle.Point3_3D = faceModelPts3D[t.Third];
        faceModel3D.Add(triangle);
    }

    var faceModelGroup = new GeometryGroup();
    for (int i = 0; i < faceModel.Count; i++)
    {
        var faceTriangle = new GeometryGroup();  
        faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel3D[i].Point1_3D, faceModel3D[i].Point2_3D)); 
        faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel3D[i].Point2_3D, faceModel3D[i].Point3_3D));
        faceTriangle.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(faceModel3D[i].Point3_3D, faceModel3D[i].Point1_3D));
        faceModelGroup.Children.Add(faceTriangle); //Add lines to image
    }

    drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.LightYellow, new Pen(Brushes.LightYellow, 1.0), faceModelGroup);
}

private struct FaceModelTriangle3D
{
     public Point3D Point1_3D;
     public Point3D Point2_3D;
     public Point3D Point3_3D;
}
```

I am currently getting the error 
"Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D' to 'System.Windows.Point'    F:\Work\Uni\4th Year\Final Year Project\Project\Project 3.0\Project 3.0\FaceTrackingViewer.xaml.cs  275 68  Project 3.0
"

Which is being caused by:

```
(new LineGeometry(faceModel3D[i].Point2_3D, faceModel3D[i].Point3_3D));
```

What do I need to use instead of LineGeometry to get this working or is there a much more effective way of doing this?

Also once I have created the face mesh I also want to be able to store this information to be able to calculate the distance between points on the face. So how would I go about storing the triangles information?

Answer (score 0):

The Face Tracking Basics WPF sample uses Point2D but you are using Point3D.

This means that you are passing in a 3D coordinate to the LineGeometry constructor, which is for 2D drawing.  You need to convert the 3D world coordinate to a 2D screen coordinate; a process known as projection.

WPF includes a perspective camera class which should be up to the job

```
System.Windows.Media.Media3D.PerspectiveCamera
```

Take a look into creating a 3D scene in WPF - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752082.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you need to project from 3D to 2D. However, instead of rolling your own projection, you should use the Kinect framework's calibrated projection method:

```
Microsoft.Kinect.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint()
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj883696.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> [How to get mesh from kinect fracetrack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043315/how-to-get-mesh-from-kinect-fracetrack/23047316#23047316)

And for the second question: 
Triangle information gives you the faces, so if you would like to store it in e.g. a .obj, then

1. Vertices: v x y z

   (x,y,z should be replaced with the corresponding numbers representing the coordinates, whereas v is to indicate you are listing the vertices)
2. Faces from triangle: f i j k

   (x,y,z should be replaced with the corresponding numbers representing the coordinates, whereas f is to indicate you are listing the faces)

amd you have your .obj

If you would store it in the program, then I would suggest two containers (probably array or linked-list depending on what you want), one for the vertices, and one for the faces or have a class to store all.