# How to get mesh from kinect fracetrack?

Tags: windows, kinect, mesh, kinect-sdk

How do I get the kinect facetracking mesh?

> this is the mesh: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPtJt.jpg

I have tried several ways, but could not make it work.

> e.g.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **3D Face Model Provided by IFTModel Interface**
>
> The Face Tracking SDK also tries to fit a 3D mask to the user’s face.
>   The 3D model is based on the Candide3 model
>   (http://www.icg.isy.liu.se/candide/) :
>
> > Note: 
> >     This model is not returned directly at each call to the Face Tracking
> >     SDK, but can be computed from the AUs and SUs.

There is no direct functionality to do that. You have to use the triangle and vertex data to generate the necessary vertex and indices lists that are required.
***GetTriangles method*** gets you the faces *(indexes of the vertices of the triangles in a clockwise fashion)*, and then from using these indexes for the array of vertices to get the 3d model. Array of vertices has to be reconstructed every frame from the AUs and SUs with ***Get3DShape or GetProjectedShape (2D) functions.***

For more, search for IFTModel (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx) and for visualizeFaceModel (a sample code, which can help in understanding the input parameters of *get3DShape*).
(This sample uses the getProjectedShape, but the input parameters are nearly identical for both functions)